# What is the benefit of using assigning a default value to a parameter in a function in python

Tags: python, function, default-value

Python allows us to set a value to a parameter by default. The following example is taken from **A smarter way to learn python** by *Mark Myers*.

```
def calc_tax(sales_total,tax_rate=0.04):
    print(sales_total * tax_rate)
```

I don't understand what is its use when we can do this:

```
def calc_tax(sales_total):
    print(sales_total*0.04)
```

Comment: What if you want to make that calculation with a different tax rate…?

Comment: This is _default_ value and it means it can be changed by passing another number for `tax_rate` but in second approach `tax_rate` is `0.04` always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because when doing:

```
def calc_tax(sales_total,tax_rate=0.04):
    print(sales_total * tax_rate)
```

You can do:

```
calc_tax(100)
```

Then here `tax_rate` is an argument that's assigned to a default value so can change it by:

```
calc_tax(any thing here,any thing here)
```

OR:

```
calc_tax(any thing here,tax_rate=any thing here)
```

So in the other-hand, this code:

```
def calc_tax(sales_total):
    print(sales_total*0.04)
```

Is is only able to do:

```
calc_tax(any thing here)
```

Because there is no second argument

Answer (score 0):

Default parameters are a language agnostic feature designed to help programmers.
Let us consider your example

```
def calc_tax(sales_total,tax_rate=0.04):
    print(sales_total * tax_rate)
```

We can call the function as

```
calc_tax(100)
```

(Notice how I dont even have to mention 0.04 as the function will automatically take the default value)
and

```
calc_tax(100,0.09)
```

Where in the first case , the default value of tax_rate i.e. 0.04 is used and you get a same answer as what

```
print(sales_total*0.04)
```

Now, if at any point you want to change this value , say to 0.09 then by your method we would have to go to the source code and modify the function. Sometimes this isn't entirely possible or may not be as simple as the example you provided , as in the case where this tax_rate is used multiple times in the function.

If you are 100% sure that a value will never change , for like constants like pi then in that case they are not passed into the function parameters but for other cases it is both simpler and more efficient to use default parameters.